# Java variable datatype in POJO for Oracles TIMESTAMP(6) type

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a Oracle table with column names as below

```
Name            Type    
------------------------------

TITLE           VARCHAR2(1024)
CREATED_ON      TIMESTAMP(6)
```

The sample value of `CREATED_ON` column is `26-JUL-17 06.59.08.290000000 AM`

I am creating a Java POJO class which should have a variable **createdOn** which accepts timestamp of that format. Not sure how that can be handled in Java even after checking various articles.

Comment: How do you connect to the database?

Comment: The date format can be printed as below in standalone class

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSS");

     `String strDate = formatter.format(date).toString().toUpperCase();   
  
     System.out.println("Format "+strDate);`

But how can this be applied to a pojo variable

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
@Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created_on;
```

Comment: I am not using Hibernate . . using Spring JDBC for db operations